# The argument type 'MaterialApp Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget?'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

recently i am trying to run from github but in pub get i am getting this kind of error like this

The argument type 'MaterialApp Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget?)'

the main code that effected are this

```
 return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: Size(428.0, 926.0),
        builder: () => MaterialApp(
          title: 'MMAS',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            textTheme: TextTheme(
              headline3: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                fontSize: 45.0,
                color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              ),
              button: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
              ),
              subtitle1: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'NotoSans'),
              bodyText2: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'NotoSans'),
            ),
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.indigo)
                .copyWith(secondary: Colors.orange),
            textSelectionTheme:
                TextSelectionThemeData(cursorColor: Colors.amberAccent),
          ),
          builder: (context, widget) => MediaQuery(
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1),
            child: widget!,
          ),
          home: SignIn(),
          // Home(),
          locale: _locale,
          localizationsDelegates: [
            AppLocalization.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
            for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
              if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale!.languageCode &&
                  supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
                return supportedLocale;
              }
            }
            return supportedLocales.first;
          },
          supportedLocales: [
            Locale("en", "US"),
            Locale("de", "DE"),
            Locale("es", "ES"),
            Locale("fr", "FR"),
            Locale("hi", "IN"),
            Locale("ja", "JP"),
            Locale("ko", "KR"),
            Locale("pt", "PT"),
            Locale("ru", "RU"),
            Locale("tr", "TR"),
            Locale("vi", "VN"),
            Locale("zh", "CN"),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi it is a common issue while using `ScreenUtilInit` widget, you need to add `BuildContext` in the `builder` method of the `ScreenUtilInit` to make it work such as:

```
return ScreenUtilInit(
    designSize: Size(428.0, 926.0),
    builder: (BuildContext context,child) => MaterialApp(
```

It should fix your issue

Comment: Hello Risheek Mittal, its work thank you for your help really appreciated it

Comment: sure i am want but need more reputation cause i am still new

Comment: No issue bro just have fun

Comment: yes brother have a nice day for you